# Find duplicate cells in multiple excel sheets

Tags: excel, duplicates, rows

I have an excel sheet with multiple spreadsheets. There are columns 'firstname' and 'lastname' of about 1000 rows in each of the spreadsheets. I have recorded a macro which shows me the duplicate rows having in the format '`firstname lastname`'.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$1000=B2)*1,($C$2:$C$1000=C2)*1)>1,"Duplicates","No duplicates")
```

The above formula can find duplicate rows in one sheet. How do I tweak the formula so that it can match with the other sheets as well. A formula or VBA will also do.

Comment: For versions of Excel that are 2007 or later, your existing formula would be better with the vastly more efficient COUNTIFS() function like this: `=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, C:C, C2)-1, "Duplicates", "No duplicates")`. No need to worry about full column references as it will only process to the extent of your data as opposed to `SUMPRODUCT(...)` processing every cell range reference verbatim. Unfortunately, you cannot simply add a multiple sheet reference to the criteria range like `Sheet1:Sheet3!B:B`.

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you for the COUNTIFS() function. Its more smaller, cleaner and efficient. And apart from COUNTIFS(), is there any other function I could use so that the duplicates are also found from another sheets.

Comment: There is no native function within Excel that accepts criteria in what is commonly referred to as a 3D range reference (i.e. a range of one or more cells on more than one worksheet). If you only had a few worksheets to look at I would suggest simply adding several `COUNTIFS(...)` together. If you had more than a few then a UDF might be the better route.

Answer (score 0):

You can fool Excel into accepting a 3D range reference as a parameter of `COUNTIFS` with `INDIRECT` and array processing courtesy of a `SUMPRODUCT` wrapper. With the names of the worksheets to be processed in Z2:Z4 then this will count duplicates across the worksheets for the first and last names in columns B & C.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$Z$2:$Z$4&"'!B:B"),B2,INDIRECT("'"&$Z$2:$Z$4&"'!C:C"),C2))`

You should be able to incorporate that standard formula into your `IF()` statement for duplicate recognition.

Please note that `INDIRECT` is considered a *volatile* function that recalculates with any change in the workbook. Depending upon the extent of your data it is likely that you will experience some calculation lag.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to implement your function. I didn't really get the IF() statement part.

Comment: @Roland - The formula simple delivers a count across multiple worksheets (in the same columns). A count of one would mean no duplicates and anything higher than that would be representative of duplicate values. e.g. `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$Z$2:$Z$4&"'!B:B"),B2,INDIRECT("'"&$Z$2:$Z$4&"'!C:C"),C2))-1, "Duplicates", "No duplicates")`.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, I tried using your answer. But I guess I am doing something wrong. Anyways as for a workaround, I copied all the data in one sheet and used =IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, C:C, C2)-1, "Duplicates", "No duplicates"). Not the best way but still. Thanks for your help !